# How to find numbers from a string?

Tags: string, vba, excel

I need to find numbers from a `string`. How does one find numbers from a `string` in VBA Excel?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Assuming you mean you want the non-numbers stripped out, you should be able to use something like:

```
Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String
    ' Variables needed (remember to use "option explicit").   '
    Dim retval As String    ' This is the return string.      '
    Dim i As Integer        ' Counter for character position. '

    ' Initialise return string to empty                       '
    retval = ""

    ' For every character in input string, copy digits to     '
    '   return string.                                        '
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
            retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
    Next

    ' Then return the return string.                          '
    onlyDigits = retval
End Function
```

Calling this with:

```
Dim myStr as String
myStr = onlyDigits ("3d1fgd4g1dg5d9gdg")
MsgBox (myStr)
```

will give you a dialog box containing:

```
314159
```

and those first two lines show how you can store it into an arbitrary string variable, to do with as you wish.

Comment: Thanks it works. Sorry i am asking very basic question i want to use this 'onlydigits' value for input to another method.

Comment: No problems, @user905527, I've updated the sample code at the end to show how you put it into a variable and pass it to another function.

Comment: You can reduce the number of comparisons with the IsNumeric function.
if IsNumeric(Mid(s,i,1)) then

Comment: I digits of Pi a co incidence?

Comment: @ArulxZ, coincidence, no. I tend to use `pi`, `e`, `xyzzy`, `plugh`, `42` and other "magical" items quite a bit :-)

Comment: First Try Failed, my assumption is due to my string having `155(Str)`

Answer (score 23):

Regular expressions are built to parse. While the syntax can take a while to pick up on this approach is very efficient, and is very flexible for handling more complex string extractions/replacements

```
Sub Tester()
     MsgBox CleanString("3d1fgd4g1dg5d9gdg")
End Sub

Function CleanString(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
     .Global = True
     .Pattern = "[^\d]+"
    CleanString = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: `+1` for using `regex`, I am really glad we can use it in VBA, it adds some ***coolness*** to VBA's *`dim` `dim` lighting culture* =)

Comment: While regex is the most elegant, does regex cause a performance hit on a large scale?

Comment: @DarylBennett Great question. Instantiating the object can cause a hit equivalent or worse than a loop. But if the object is instantiated once (say in an array loop) and run repeatedly it is extremely efficient.

Comment: Perhaps add [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/111794) to your answer? Admittedly, the question is phrased in terms of Excel-hosted VBA, but most of the information applies equally well to any VBA host.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on brettdj's answer, in order to parse disjoint embedded digits into separate numbers:

```
Sub TestNumList()
    Dim NumList As Variant  'Array

    NumList = GetNums("34d1fgd43g1 dg5d999gdg2076")

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(NumList) To UBound(NumList)
        MsgBox i + 1 & ": " & NumList(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Function GetNums(ByVal strIn As String) As Variant  'Array of numeric strings
    Dim RegExpObj As Object
    Dim NumStr As String

    Set RegExpObj = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RegExpObj
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[^\d]+"
        NumStr = .Replace(strIn, " ")
    End With

    GetNums = Split(Trim(NumStr), " ")
End Function
```

Comment: Fantastic, I always missed RegEx in VBA! See also: [VBScript’s Regular Expression Support](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in VBA function Val, if the numbers are at the front end of the string:

```
Dim str as String
Dim lng as Long

str = "1 149 xyz"
lng = Val(str)
```

lng = 1149

[Val Function, on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/val-function)

Comment: `Val` does some very strange things: `Val("3d1fgd4g1dg5d9gdg")` returns `30`, while `Va("3d11gd4g1dg5d9gdg")` returns `300000000000`.

Comment: @zev-spitz Noted: very odd behaviour. I see that the anomalous results in your examples above are triggered, respectively, but the first three or four characters; hence `Val("3d1")` and `Val("3d11")` respectively return 30 and 300000000000.

Comment: Interprets as floating point values (I don't know why): 3d1=3*10^1; 3d11=3*10^11. Do not use Val()!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the answer of the same question but for a while I found my own solution and I wanted to share it for other people who will need those codes in the future. Here is another solution without function.

```
Dim control As Boolean
Dim controlval As String
Dim resultval As String
Dim i as Integer

controlval = "A1B2C3D4"

For i = 1 To Len(controlval)
control = IsNumeric(Mid(controlval, i, 1))
If control = True Then resultval = resultval & Mid(controlval, i, 1)
Next i
```

resultval = 1234

Answer (score 0):

This a variant of brettdj's & pstraton post.

This will return a true Value and not give you the `#NUM!` error. And `\D` is shorthand for anything but digits. The rest is much like the others only with this minor fix.

```
Function StripChar(Txt As String) As Variant
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\D"
    StripChar = Val(.Replace(Txt, " "))
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7239408/8740349), but is just reformated:

Assuming you mean you want the non-numbers stripped out, you should be able to use something like:

```vb
'
' Skips all characters in the input string except digits
'
Function GetDigits(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim char As String
    Dim i As Integer
    GetDigits = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        char = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If char >= "0" And char <= "9" Then
            GetDigits = GetDigits + char
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Calling this with:

```
Dim myStr as String
myStr = GetDigits("3d1fgd4g1dg5d9gdg")
Call MsgBox(myStr)
```

will give you a dialog box containing:

```
314159
```

and those first two lines show how you can store it into an arbitrary string variable, to do with as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative via `Byte` Array**

If you assign a string to a `Byte` array you typically get the number equivalents of each character in pairs of the array elements. Use a loop for numeric check via the `Like` operator and return the joined array as string:

```
Function Nums(s$)
  Dim by() As Byte, i&, ii&
  by = s: ReDim tmp(UBound(by))                    ' assign string to byte array; prepare temp array
  For i = 0 To UBound(by) - 1 Step 2               ' check num value in byte array (0, 2, 4 ... n-1)
      If Chr(by(i)) Like "#" Then tmp(ii) = Chr(by(i)): ii = ii + 1
  Next i
  Nums = Trim(Join(tmp, vbNullString))             ' return string with numbers only
  End Function
```

**Example call**

```
Sub testByteApproach()
  Dim s$: s = "a12bx99y /\:3,14159"                 ' [1] define original string
  Debug.Print s & " => " & Nums(s)                  ' [2] display original string and result
End Sub
```

*would display the original string and the result string in the immediate window:*

```
  a12bx99y /\:3,14159 => 1299314159
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @brettdj's answer using a VBScript regex ojbect with two modifications:

- The function handles variants and returns a variant. That is, to take care of a null case; and
- Uses explicit object creation, with a reference to the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" library

```vb
Function GetDigitsInVariant(inputVariant As Variant) As Variant
  ' Returns:
  '     Only the digits found in a varaint.
  ' Examples:
  '     GetDigitsInVariant(Null) => Null
  '     GetDigitsInVariant("") => ""
  '     GetDigitsInVariant(2021-/05-May/-18, Tue) => 20210518
  '     GetDigitsInVariant(2021-05-18) => 20210518
  ' Notes:
  '     If the inputVariant is null, null will be returned.
  '     If the inputVariant is "", "" will be returned.
  ' Usage:
  '     VBA IDE Menu > Tools > References ...
  '       > "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" > [OK]

  ' With an explicit object reference to RegExp we can get intellisense
  ' and review the object heirarchy with the object browser
  ' (VBA IDE Menu > View > Object Browser).
  Dim regex As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
  Set regex = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
  
  Dim result As Variant
  result = Null
  
  If IsNull(inputVariant) Then
    result = Null
    
  Else
    With regex
      .Global = True
      .Pattern = "[^\d]+"
      result = .Replace(inputVariant, vbNullString)
    End With
  End If
  
  GetDigitsInVariant = result
End Function
```

Testing:

```vb
Private Sub TestGetDigitsInVariant()
  Dim dateVariants As Variant
  dateVariants = Array(Null, "", "2021-/05-May/-18, Tue", _
          "2021-05-18", "18/05/2021", "3434 ..,sdf,sfd 444")
  
  Dim dateVariant As Variant
  For Each dateVariant In dateVariants
    Debug.Print dateVariant & ": ", , GetDigitsInVariant(dateVariant)
  Next dateVariant
  Debug.Print
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function ExtractChars(strRef$) As String
'Extract characters from a string according to a range of charactors e.g'+.-1234567890'
  Dim strA$, e%, strExt$, strCnd$: strExt = "": strCnd = "+.-1234567890"
  For e = 1 To Len(strRef): strA = Mid(strRef, e, 1)
    If InStr(1, strCnd, strA) > 0 Then strExt = strExt & strA
  Next e: ExtractChars = strExt
End Function
```

In the immediate debug dialog:

? ExtractChars("a-5d31.78K")

-531.78

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The function returns any characters in the strings, example  '+.-1234567890'