# How to extract groups of numbers from a string in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string of the following shape:

```
RRP 90 AVE DE GAULLE 92800 PUTEAUX 0109781431-0149012126
```

The numbers might be seperated by other chars than hyphens (eg spaces). I know how to differentiate them afterwards with len().

I need every string of numbers to be stored seperately (in an array for example), so that I can discriminate them with len() and then use them.

I have found how to strip the characters away from the string : 
[How to find numbers from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239328/vba-how-to-find-numbers-from-string)

But it doesn't suit my problem...

Could you direct me to a function or bit of code that could help me with that?

Comment: Regular expressions...

Comment: Do you need some separation between the groups of numbers in the results? Is "909280001097814310149012126" OK or do you need "90 92800 0109781431 0149012126" as the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will run much faster than looping

```
Public Function NumericOnly(s As String) As String
    Dim s2 As String
    Dim replace_hyphen As String
    replace_hyphen = " "
    Static re As RegExp
    If re Is Nothing Then Set re = New RegExp
    re.IgnoreCase = True
    re.Global = True
    re.Pattern = "[^0-9 -]" 'includes space, if you want to exclude space "[^0-9]"
    s2 = re.Replace(s, vbNullString)
    re.Pattern = "[^0-9 ]"
    NumericOnly = re.Replace(s2, replace_hyphen)
End Function
```

Comment: This one returns me nothing, I'm reading about regex to understand why.

Comment: with this code `RRP 90 AVE DE GAULLE 92800 PUTEAUX 0109781431-0149012126` returns  `90    92800  01097814310149012126`  by typing `=numericonly(B1)` where the text string is in `B1`

Comment: Thanks, that way, it works...but, the last string needs to be seperated where the hyphen is...

Comment: try my edit, this should create a space for the hyphen, any other characters you need to turn into spaces similar to hyphen, then add it to the `"[^0-9 -]"` list

Comment: It appears it is not exactly what I need and still can't figure out the answer by myself. I still need to be able to seperate my string to  an array of string so that I can process each part of it. Also I need to add others characters (such as "//" or "/") than the hyphen as a seperator, but I can't figure out how you really did and how to replacate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
Function parseNum(strSearch As String) As String

   ' Dim strSearch As String
    'strSearch = "RRP 90 AVE DE GAULLE 92800 PUTEAUX 0109781431-0149012126"

    Dim i As Integer, tempVal As String
    For i = 1 To Len(strSearch)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(strSearch, i, 1)) Then
            tempVal = tempVal + Mid(strSearch, i, 1)
        End If
    Next

    parseNum = tempVal
End Function
```

Comment: @Chipsgoumerde how do you want the numbers to appear ? Do you want to add them ?

Comment: nop, it's not for calculation, but to search for the number in another worksheet/column. To clarify : I will check for every group of numbers : if it's 9 digits> search for it in column A / if it's 10 digits long search for it in column B

Comment: @Chipsgoumerde How do you want to group the numbers ?

Comment: RRP 90 AVE DE GAULLE 92800 PUTEAUX 0109781431-0149012126 => I want to have 90 / 92800 / 0109781431 / 0149012126

Answer (score 0):

So I realize this was a long time ago... but I was looking for a similar solution online.

Some previous history  on my programming skillz (sic): I started with Python and with Python I have a handy tool called `List`. VBA doesn't have this, so what I'm left with is something that I can input in a variable I called `sample` below, i.e. `sample = [1,4,5]`.

Back to the small code. I made it so `holder` would only contain groups of numbers, as how you specified they should be grouped.

```
Dim count, count1 As Integer
Dim holder As String
Dim sample, smallSample As String


count = 0
count1 = 1
sample = "1ab33 efa 123 adfije-23423 123124-23423"
holder = ""
Do While count <> Len(sample)
    smallSample = Left(sample, 1)
    If smallSample = "0" Or smallSample = "1" Or smallSample = "2" Or smallSample = "3" Or smallSample = "4" Or smallSample = "5" Or smallSample = "6" Or smallSample = "7" Or smallSample = "8" Or smallSample = "9" Then
        holder = holder & smallSample
    Else
        If holder <> "" Then
            Cells(count1,1) = holder
            count1 = count1 + 1
        End If
        holder = ""
    End If
    sample = Right(sample, Len(sample) - 1)

Loop
```

The output I got was

> 1
>
> 33
>
> 123
>
> 23423
>
> 123124

after I ran the code.

Answer (score 0):

Great Simple Python-style loop above.

Extended for a list of strings in column A.

The numbers discovered will show in the columns to the right - B, C, etc.

```
Dim count, count1 As Integer
Dim holder As String
Dim sample, smallSample As String
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
r = 1
c = 1


Do While Sheet2.Cells(r, c) <> ""
    count = 0
    count1 = 1
    sample = Sheet2.Cells(r, c)
    holder = ""
    Do While count <> Len(sample)
        smallSample = Left(sample, 1)
        If smallSample = "0" Or smallSample = "1" Or smallSample = "2" Or smallSample = "3" Or smallSample = "4" Or smallSample = "5" Or smallSample = "6" Or smallSample = "7" Or smallSample = "8" Or smallSample = "9" Then
            holder = holder & smallSample
        Else
            If holder <> "" Then
                Sheets(2).Cells(r, c + count1).Value = holder
                count1 = count1 + 1
            End If
            holder = ""
        End If
        sample = Right(sample, Len(sample) - 1)
    
    Loop
    r = r + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting the Error "Issue while compiling, user defined type not defined" while using @Scotts Answer Enable the Regular Expression option as seen in Step 1 and 2 here: [How to Use/Enable (RegExp object) Regular Expression using VBA (MACRO) in word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102372/how-to-use-enable-regexp-object-regular-expression-using-vba-macro-in-word) (Works in Excel also)

P.s. Scotts Solution worked well for me.