# How to Use/Enable (RegExp object) Regular Expression using VBA (MACRO) in word

Tags: regex, vba, visual-studio-macros

I did lot of Googling to get a proper answer on how to use or start using Regular Expressions in VBA.

At last I got it so I'd like to share my knowledge with you guys. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/1255289)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

By default Regular Expression option is disabled in word 2007, to enable that plase do following steps,

1). Go to Tools > References as shown below.
   [image]

2). Now put a tick on "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" option and then press oh as shown below.
[image]

3). Now onward you can create a RegExp object in your VBA script. You can verify it be searching in object data base as explained below.
View > Object Browser ( Or press F2) , as shown below.

[image]

and search for RegExp object

[image]

4). 
The **RegExp** object uses regular expressions to match a pattern. The following properties are provided by **RegExp**. These properties set the pattern to compare the strings that are passed to the **RegExp** instance:

***a.*** **Pattern:** A string that defines the regular expression.

***b.*** **IgnoreCase:** A Boolean property that indicates whether you must test the regular expression against all possible matches in a string.

***c.*** **Global:** Sets a Boolean value or returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a pattern must match all the occurrences in a whole search string, or whether a pattern must match just the first occurrence.

**RegExp** provides the following methods to determine whether a string matches a particular pattern of a regular expression:

***d.*** **Test:** Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the regular expression can successfully be matched against the string.

***e.*** **Execute:** Returns a MatchCollection object that contains a Match object for each successful match.

Please find a simile example for RexExp provided in Microsoft msdn forum.

```
Function TestRegExp(myPattern As String, myString As String)
   'Create objects.
   Dim objRegExp As RegExp
   Dim objMatch As Match
   Dim colMatches   As MatchCollection
   Dim RetStr As String

   ' Create a regular expression object.
   Set objRegExp = New RegExp

   'Set the pattern by using the Pattern property.
   objRegExp.Pattern = myPattern

   ' Set Case Insensitivity.
   objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True

   'Set global applicability.
   objRegExp.Global = True

   'Test whether the String can be compared.
   If (objRegExp.Test(myString) = True) Then

   'Get the matches.
    Set colMatches = objRegExp.Execute(myString)   ' Execute search.

    For Each objMatch In colMatches   ' Iterate Matches collection.
      RetStr = RetStr & "Match found at position "
      RetStr = RetStr & objMatch.FirstIndex & ". Match Value is '"
      RetStr = RetStr & objMatch.Value & "'." & vbCrLf
    Next
   Else
    RetStr = "String Matching Failed"
   End If
   TestRegExp = RetStr
End Function
```

I hope it might help full for some one, because i wasted almost half a day on it.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem in Excel for Mac 2011. However, after opening up the References list, there is no library that would activate the RegExp object. How would I add this library to the list for selection?

Comment: I see that this question for Mac has been asked before... not looking good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344932/regex-with-vba-excel-at-mac

Comment: your post was great! In fact, after searching the web 4 different places. I got to here! Thank you.