# RegEx in Outlook VBA to get text from Email Body

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

I need to extract text from an email body using a RegEx. I'm using Outlook 2010 with the MS VBScript 5.5 regex engine. The text i'm trying to extract is:

```
MessageID                              :1079247881
InstrumentID                         :DS5431460001
```

So far, I've come up with:

```
MessageID\s*\:(\d+)\n
InstrumentID\s+\:([a-z]{2}\d+)\n
```

Both are working now. Here are my tests:

[InstrumentID](https://regex101.com/r/bX3lJ9/5)

[MessageID](https://regex101.com/r/bX3lJ9/6)

Ultimately, I want to highlight a specific message and run my code. It will then extract those 2 items from that message and put them into a template for me to send. I'm doing ok on that part. I just need help with the RegExs.

Comment: Ok, I've figured out the first one and updated my post. Now working on the  second one.

Comment: So, what do you still need? You want *one* regex for both cases?

Comment: I figured out both of them and updated my post.

Comment: So is there anything else you need? Also note that `\w{2}\d+` is a strange construct. `\w` doesn't only check alphabetical, but rather alphanumerical values. What you may need is `[a-z]{2}\d+`.

Comment: @BramVanroy Is that possible? I'm not really sure if I need it because I think I can just do submatches(0) and (1). It would be cool to see it though.

Comment: My current answer provides a good regex, however I'm unsure how you can return *all* matches in VB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work with one regular expression, you could do something like this:

```
(?:Message|Instrument)ID\s+:(\w+)
```

I am unfamiliar with VB and its regexes implementation, but it seems you can do something like this (adapted and borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25102373/1150683)).

```
Function TestRegExp(myString As String)
   'Create objects.
   Dim objRegExp As RegExp
   Dim objMatch As Match
   Dim colMatches   As MatchCollection
   Dim RetStr As String

   ' Create a regular expression object.
   Set objRegExp = New RegExp

   'Set the pattern by using the Pattern property.
   objRegExp.Pattern = "(?:message|instrument)ID\s+:(\w+)"

   ' Set Case Insensitivity.
   objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True

   'Set global applicability.
   objRegExp.Global = True

   'Test whether the String can be compared.
   If (objRegExp.Test(myString) = True) Then

   'Get the matches.
    Set colMatches = objRegExp.Execute(myString)   ' Execute search.



If (objRegExp.Test(myString) = True) Then

'Get the matches.
Set colMatches = objRegExp.Execute(myString)   ' Execute search.

For Each objMatch In colMatches   ' Iterate Matches collection.
  MsgBox objMatch.SubMatches(0)
Next
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Bram this only matches the first one though. I was doing something similar to this using the Pipe before but that wasn't working either.

Comment: @MattWilliamson As you can see, there is a `for each` loop near the end, which should iterate over all matches.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I wrote my comment before the post was updated with the VBA code.

Comment: @MattWilliamson I updated the code again. Have a look!

Comment: Thanks again Bram. I had to use a loop with the submatches collection. I updated your code to reflect this.