# Get a specific Line in a body of email vba outlook

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Every time the mail is received, I want to print out a specific word in a body of email:

---------------------------------Body of email-------------------------------------

Sender Name: John

Sender's Address: john@sample-mail.com

Subject: Mail Subject from John  *<----- the line that I want to get*

--------------------------------------End------------------------------------------

My Code:

```
Private WithEvents olItems As Outlook.Items


Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub

Private Sub Application_Startup()

  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace

  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set olItems = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Watchlisted").Items

End Sub

Private Sub olItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  Dim BodySubjLine As String, BodySubj As Variant
  
  Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachment
  
  Set olMail = Item
  
  BodySubj = Split(olMail.Body, vbNewLine)
  BodySubjLine = Trim(BodySubj(2))
  
  Debug.Print BodySubjLine 
  
  Set olMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Expected output:

```
Subject: Mail Subject from John
```

The output I get gives nothing at all

Comment: What does `Debug.Print UBound(BodySubj)` get you?   You don't see any error?  Try looping over `BodySubj` and printing each element along with its index, so you can figure out which one you want.  It's possible you may want to use `vbCrLf` for the Split, instead of `vbLf`

Comment: ```Debug.Print UBound(BodySubj)``` does nothing though, but the looping did give me an idea. Thx :)

Comment: It doesn't do nothing - the output should be in the Immediate window in the VB editor.

Comment: Another method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001670/search-structured-text-in-outlook-body

Answer (score 1):

You could use breakpoints to debug the code.

Instead of

```
BodySubj = Split(olMail.Body, vbNewLine)
```

Use

```
BodySubj = Split(olMail.Body, Chr(10) & Chr(13))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on message body lines you can use regular expressions to extract the exact substrings, read more about that:

- [RegEx in Outlook VBA to get text from Email Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070693/regex-in-outlook-vba-to-get-text-from-email-body)
- [Use RegEx to extract text from an Outlook email message](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/regex-parse-message-text/)

Comment: thx for your suggestion but i already made the code. I will try this :)