# How to differentiate incoming mail where subjects have same beginning text?

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

I have created a rule where the subject line contains

```
A Document has been assigned to You
```

It also routes the emails with subject

```
A Document has been assigned to Your group
```

How can I fix this? Is there a regular expression available?

Comment: See if you can run an earlier rule on the unwanted subject to "Stop processing more rules".

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a VBA macro that can handle incoming emails. The `NewMailEx` event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the `NameSpace.GetItemFromID` method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance.

```
Public WithEvents outApp As Outlook.Application

Sub Intialize_Handler()
    Set outApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub outApp_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim mai As Object

    Set mai = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)
    MsgBox mai.Subject

End Sub
```

You can use regular expression in VBA macros, see [How to Use/Enable (RegExp object) Regular Expression using VBA (MACRO) in word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102372/how-to-use-enable-regexp-object-regular-expression-using-vba-macro-in-word) for more information.