# Passing a string to be used within a CASE statement

Tags: vba

this is my first time posting a question here.  I am writing an MS Excel VBA project where I am passing a string between subroutines.  In the second subroutine I am using the string to determine CASE conditions.  EG 4000 to 9999; 4050 to 5000, 5050; 5051 to 6000, 6051 to 7000 being three examples.  When these strings are typed after the CASE, it works , but passing the values as a string doesn't.  My project involves the running of the sub many times with the case statement being required to change every time.  Any Suggestions?

Many thanks
NC
here is a sample of my code.  I have left out all the dims and calculations - I am positive that these would not help,
thanks

```
Sub Calling_Sub ()
'Operating Income
Title = "Operating Income"
GL_Range = "5000 to 9499"
add_me_up Title, GL_Range

'Other Income
Title = "Other Income"
GL_Range = "4050 to 5000, 5050"
add_me_up Title, GL_Range

'Debts
Title = "Debts"
GL_Range = "5051 to 6000, 6051 to 7000"
add_me_up Title, GL_Range

'Other
Title = "Other"
GL_Range = "8051, 8055, 8070, 8075"
add_me_up Title, GL_Range

'and so on and so forth for all the other combinations
End Sub


Sub add_me_up (Title as string, GL_Range as string)

...

For Each lrowC In lrngC.Cells       'pivot table data rows

   Select Case lrowC.Cells.Offset(0, 1)

        Case ****GL_Range****
            If lrowC.Cells(1, 1) = Fin_Year Then      'current month & YTD
                Select Case Period
                    Case 1
...

end sub
```

Comment: Could you post your code example please?

Comment: Sub Calling_Sub ()
    'Operating Income
    Title = "Operating Income"
    GL_Range = "5000 to 9499"
    add_me_up Title, GL_Range

    
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether that is just wrong due to your code-reduction, but you have to call the `add_me_up`-routine with `Call` and brackets. E.g. like this:

```
Call add_me_up(Title, GL_Range)
```

Check it out on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251432.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Klaster, it has no trouble calling the second sub, only that when it gets into the select case, case GL_Range sees the string as a literal alpha, and not as the values I want it to.  EG.  I want it to read :-
Case 5000 to 9499
but it gets :-
Case "5000 to 9499"

Comment: Okay, now I get it. Handing the numbers not as Strings makes perfectly sense, obviously. If you don't want to change `calling_sub`, you could also parse the numbers from the string. There are [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369485/how-to-extract-groups-of-numbers-from-a-string-in-vba) on Stackoverflow already.

Comment: Thanks again Klaster, sadly the obvious took me longer, actually when I responded to you initially was when the solution hit me. Parsing was also a very valid option, and one I will probably use next time. I thank you sincerely for your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, but I have a workable solution.  I am now passing the numbers separate to the 'joiners', and by this, the case statement is able to read them as numbers, as opposed to the alpha strings previously.  I appreciate any thoughts given to my problem, thanks.