# Excel: How to add only the values from one cell, skipping other text and characters?

Tags: excel

[image]I have values such as below in one single cell E2 in excel. How do I skip the paranthesis, space and the text that is there in the cell and add only the values enclosed within the brackets and show the result in D2? 
(5) text
(5) text
(5) text
(10) text
(10) text
(15) text
(10) text
(10) text
(20) text
(10) text

I've attached an image to show an idea of how it looks.

Comment: If you are open to and conversant with VBA, you may want to try this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369485/how-to-extract-groups-of-numbers-from-a-string-in-vba)

Comment: Is ***text*** always the same for every value ??

Comment: No, the text differs for each.

Comment: "I've attached an image to show an idea of how it looks." ?

Comment: Where's the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"text"," ")),"(",""),")",""))," ","")
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation as to what this does? It's difficult to follow with all the nested brackets. I also think that the cell type needs to be changed from text to value, but I'm not sure if this macro does that.

Comment: @KenY-N, "substitute" is used to replaces the old text "text" with new text " ", same is followed for "(" and ")"
Below is revised version, 
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A9,"text",""),"(",""),")","")," ","")
followed by =VALUE(TRIM(A1)) would change the text to number

Comment: I've attached a screenshot above showing how it looks.

Comment: hi @MedlinGracia, we are not able to view the screenshot

Comment: Is the screenshot still not visible? I attached it twice :O

Answer (score 0):

Another,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--REPLACE(A1:A10, FIND(" ", A1:A10), LEN(A1:A10), TEXT(,)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If given input string is well formatted, I can extract the number with excel function.

```
=value(MID(F1,FIND("(",F1)+1,FIND(")",F1)-FIND("(",F1)-1))
```

This function is composed of 3 elemental functions.

```
=value(MID(  F1  ,  FIND("(",F1)+1  ,  FIND(")",F1)-FIND("(",F1)-1  ))
F1: we want to extract the number from this
FIND("(",F1)+1 : where the number start from
FIND(")",F1)-FIND("(",F1)-1 : calculates the length of the number
MID:extract a string
value :deal(cast) a string as a number
```

Comment: Sorry, my function returns a string. if we want to calculate with extracted value, we need change a string into a number. Excel's value function can be used for this purpose, I update my answer.