# How to search numeric value from a range in excel

Tags: excel, range, formula

I want to match the numeric code : 123456 from a range which includes different alphanumeric codes like IFCW123456-BLACK.

Can you please suggest some excel formula for this.

Thanks.

Comment: You can extract the numbers from the string
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239328/vba-how-to-find-numbers-from-string

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use function FIND:

=**FIND**(123456, <*cells interval*>)