# Stripping out Non Numerical Characters using a Query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Light user of MS Access so not a power user by any means.

Ok, to explain what I want first of all.

I have two tables, one with a username `XXX99999` ( 3 Alpha 5 Numeric ) and the other one just `99999` ( 5 numeric ).

They are one in the same, for the most part I can safely drop the first 3 letters and perform what I need to 'link' using the last 5 Numeric digits only.

I imagine doing this by a query.

My question is, how would I mask this to build my query.

All 5 Numeric are unique.

Comment: You can use `Right([field-name],5)` in your query, but I see hazards just ahead, such as implications from "for the most part".

Answer (score 0):

If you take the function by @paxdiablo here ([VBA: How to Find Numbers from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239328/vba-how-to-find-numbers-from-string)), which is

```
Public Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String
    ' Variables needed (remember to use "option explicit").   '
    Dim retval As String    ' This is the return string.      '
    Dim i As Integer        ' Counter for character position. '

    ' Initialise return string to empty                       '
    retval = ""

    ' For every character in input string, copy digits to     '
    '   return string.                                        '
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
            retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
    Next

    ' Then return the return string.                          '
    onlyDigits = retval
End Function
```

paste it into a Module and save it, you should be able to link both tables in a query like this (assuming Table1 has the only numbers field and Table2 has the alpha and numbers):

```
SELECT Table1.MyField1, Table2.MyField2
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
ON CStr(Table1.OnlyNumbersField) = onlyDigits(Table2.TextAndNumberField);
```

This will strip the alpha characters behind the scenes, make sure both datatypes are the same, then "link" them to produce the joined result in your query.  I know you said you are not a power user and this may be complicated for you, but there is no "easy" way to do this.  I could walk you through doing it through multiple queries, which may make more sense to you, but it is a lot more to explain.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complex given we know we just need the right 5 characters each time and so could use the [RIGHT](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/right.php) function

Comment: True, but the question in the title is "stripping out non numerical characters" and I wanted to give OP a solution for that.  Never know when the data may change or OP could have overlooked something.  Hopefully he/she can take something away something from the solution, even if the RIGHT can work this time.

Comment: Ah that's very true, I arrived here from the close-vote review queue and had actually only read the body of the question and not the title. Apologies

Comment: All good, no worries.  Probably a regex solution would be the best, though.