# Excel get value depending on length of source

Tags: vba, excel

Currently we have a small bit of code that gets the value of a cell and returns 4 digits of it.

For example `L1234` would be `1234`, `D1234` would be `1234`

However now we have values that are 5 digits `L12345` for example and they are just being returned as the last 2 digits. e.g. `L12345` is being returned as `45`

What i want is to modify the code to allow for both 4 and 5 digit variants.

Current Code:

```
  If GetElm(Range("F" & i).value, 3) = "8260" Then
    CodeD = GetElm(Range("F" & i).value, 4)
  End If
  col9 = Right(CodeD, 4)
```

This returns:

```
Input   Output
L1234   1234
L12345  45
```

What I have tried:

```
  If GetElm(Range("F" & i).value, 3) = "8260" Then
    CodeD = GetElm(Range("F" & i).value, 4)
  ElseIf GetElm(Range("F" & i).value, 3) = "8260" Then
    CodeD = GetElm(Range("F" & i).value, 5)
  End If
  col9 = Right(CodeD, 5)
```

This Returns:

```
Input   Output
L1234   L1234
L12345  12345
```

This returns the 5 digit ones correctly, but the 4 digit ones are being returned with the letter.

EDIT:

GetElm Definition:

```
Function GetElm(value As String, elmno As Integer)

If elmno = 1 Then
  GetElm = Left(value, 1)
ElseIf elmno = 2 Then
  GetElm = Mid(value, 3, 3)
ElseIf elmno = 3 Then
  GetElm = Mid(value, 7, 4)
ElseIf elmno = 4 Then
  GetElm = Mid(value, 12, 8)
End If

End Function
```

Comment: What does `GetElm` do and return?

Comment: @moffeltje Added GetElm Function code

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7239408/4185106), that is actually what you want.

Comment: There's something wrong with the sample `Input` data, and/or the code. `Mid(value, 7, 4)` this part will return empty string for both 5 and 6 char input. Also `If` and `ElseIf` conditions in `What I have tried:` are the same. There is no action for `elmno=5` defined.

Comment: @moffeltje Got it working by manipulating that answer :)

Comment: I'm just curious about what the elmno parameter is for- Would you mind explaining?

Comment: Its part of a larger piece of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added function:

```
Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String
    ' Variables needed (remember to use "option explicit").   '
    Dim retval As String    ' This is the return string.      '
    Dim i As Integer        ' Counter for character position. '

    ' Initialise return string to empty                       '
    retval = ""

    ' For every character in input string, copy digits to     '
    '   return string.                                        '
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
            retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
    Next

    ' Then return the return string.                          '
    onlyDigits = retval
End Function
```

Then used the code:

```
  If GetElm(Range("F" & i).value, 3) = "8260" Then
    CodeD = GetElm(Range("F" & i).value, 4)
  End If
  col9 = onlyDigits(CodeD)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to just skip the first character, you can use:

```
col9 = Mid(CodeD, 2)
```

Comment: See updated answer - assuming I understood what GetElm was returning.

Comment: No, just replace this part: `col9 = Right(CodeD, 5)`

Comment: Nope, that returns both the 4 and 5 digits with the letter on both `L1234` & `L12345` are returned

Comment: What exactly does `GetElm` return?

Comment: Dont worry, got it working, see my answer, thanks anyway

Comment: @moffeltje Yes, I know but since it bears **no relation to any of the sample data**, I can't tell what value it returns, hence my question.

Comment: @moffeltje Yup. :) If it returns L12345 as I assumed, then `Mid` would be a simple solution, but it appears not.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to skip the first character in the cell's value, then:

```
Function GetElm (byval value as string) as string
   GetElm = Right(value, Len(value)-1)
End Function
```

should do the trick.

This assumes you always have a 1-letter, n-digits code.

Still, I don't understand the use for the second parameter in your GetElm function definition.

Regards,
Luis