# Single function to write for all message id

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Iam new to Excel VBA , I am started writing a code , which was executed fine, but I need a suggestion how to write a function where i dont need to write code for all "ID".

For example :
I have main works sheet having ID(1000x, 10000, 2000X,20000). 
I want to search only ID with number not with alphabet, and compare it with another worksheet , having the same ID , if then get the corrosponding ID 3rd column data and conacdenate all them into main worksheet .

I have main worksheet ("Tabelle1")having all the ID(10000,20000) in Coloumn A ,I want the infomration of ID 10000 in column B of ID 10000. some times i have 10000 for four times . Want to paste infomration to another worksheet ("Test_2"), I want to collect all the 10000 and corrosponding data .

```
Sub Update()
If MsgBox("Are you sure that you wish to Update New Measurement ?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
Dim erow As Long, erow1 As Long, i As Long
erow1 = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To erow1
If Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 2) <> "10000" Then
Sheets("Tabelle1").Range(Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 1), Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 2)).Copy
Sheets("Test_2").Activate
erow = Sheets("Test_2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets("Test_2").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 2))
Sheets("Test_2").Activate

End If
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False


For i = 1 To erow
Totalstrings = Totalstrings & Cells(i, 2) & "" + vbCrLf
Next i
Totalstrings = Left(Totalstrings, Len(Totalstrings) - 1)
Range("C5") = Totalstrings


Range("C5").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("BSM_STF_iO").Select
Range("C5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
 MsgBox "New measurements  have been Updated !"
End If

End Sub
```

Example

In BSM:STM:IO

A                                                                 B
ID
1000X
10000
10001
...

in Tabelle1
          B            C
          ID
          1000         abc
          1000         xyz
          10001        lmn
          2000         def
"
I want to compare only digit from"the "BSM:STM:Io" with "tabelle1". Example take the the  first value 10000 from "BSM_STM_io" compare with tabele take the the value of corrosponding Coloumn "C" in "tablle1" and put it into single cell in 1000 of BSM_STM:Io

- A , B , C are coloumn in the worksheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE1bn.jpg)
[image]

Comment: searching column A ID with same sheet of B in Tabelle1 or another sheet?

Comment: I have to fill the information let say in worksheet("BSM_STF_iO") where all the information in the worksheet ("Tabelle1"). I have to take the search with id in "BSM_STF_iO" with "Tabelle1" if it matches then i have copy the information from "tabelle1" to "BSM_STF_iO"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume worksheet "BSM_STF_iO" contains the ID information in A column beginning with A2 and worksheet Tabelle1 contains the required concaetenation information in B Column beginning from B2 (ex: Column B: IDs, Column C: information to concaetenate). Below code will concaetenate the contents and write in BSM_STF_iO sheet.

```
Sub test1()
Worksheets("BSM_STF_iO").Select
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    a = onlyDigits(Range("A" & i).Value)
    With Worksheets("Tabelle1")
        destlastrow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 2 To destlastrow
            If a = Trim(.Range("B" & j).Value) Then
                If out <> "" Then
                    out = out & ", " & .Range("C" & j).Value
                Else
                    out = .Range("C" & j).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        Cells(i, 2) = out
        out = ""
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

and below function taken from [How to find numbers from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239328/how-to-find-numbers-from-a-string)

```
Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String
    Dim retval As String
    Dim i As Integer
    retval = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
            retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    onlyDigits = retval
End Function
```

Comment: it worked fine, but i need small modification,  Ihave update as example in main . caan you please check . once again your code works good

Comment: can you please share some outputs for your example.

Comment: could you please clarify why you want the reuslts to placed at 1000  in BSM_STM_io? while we are getting the results 10000 ID

Comment: its working at my side. please accept this as solution if you satisfy

Comment: Karthik, Thanks, but you code is not comparing and placing it corrosponding ID.Its writing to all numerical ID.It could be nice if search the ID in BSM and compare it with tabelle and copy the corrosponding couloumn and paste it to appropiate ID in bsm

Comment: Hope my code help you to understand the logic. kindly go with the code and modify as per your wish.

Comment: so IDs you are mentioning in BSM:STM:Io are cell reference?