# search and update into a single cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am new to VBA excel, a week old. I have little knowledge in C , with that I have created a program.

The task is that "to search a particluar Number in one excel worksheet(1) and compare in another worksheet(2), get the corrosponding coloumn data , concatinate the information into once cell on Worksheet(1) .

I tried but I can't get the process done I need a valuable suggestion how to fix my code.

My code:

```
Sub test1()
Dim iComp
Worksheets("BSM_STF_iO").Select
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow

      a = onlyDigits(Range("A" & i).Value)
       If InStr(a, "T") Then
       Else

     Worksheets("Tabelle1").Select
        destlastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 2 To destlastrow
         b = onlyDigits(Range("B" & j).Value)
          iComp = StrComp(a, b, vbBinaryCompare)
        Select Case iComp
       Case 0
Sheets("Tabelle1").Range(Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(j, 3), Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(j, 4)).Copy
Sheets("Tabelle1").Activate
erow = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets("Tabelle1").Range(Cells(erow, 8), Cells(erow, 9))
Sheets("BSM_STF_iO").Activate
End Select
        Next j


    End If

Next i
End Sub
Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String
    Dim retval As String
    Dim i As Integer
    retval = ""
              retval = s
      onlyDigits = retval
End Function
```

Example:

I need to put all the information from "tabelle1" worksheet information of "10000" to "BSM_STF_io" 10000.

[BSM_STF_io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO5wZ.jpg)
[Tabellle1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw30y.jpg)

Comment: I recommend reading through [How to avoid `.Select`/`.Activate`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) as using them can cause some unexpected behavior.  Does you code currently give any errors? What doesn't it do that you need?

Comment: I can't concatenate the value into single cell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single function to write for all message id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36469469/single-function-to-write-for-all-message-id)

Comment: But Imodified the code here , I got it from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps (I removed the `.Activate/.Select` parts):

```
Sub test1()
Dim iComp
Dim bsmWS As Worksheet, tabWS As Worksheet

Set bsmWS = Sheets("BSM_STF_iO")
Set tabWS = Sheets("Tabelle1")

LastRow = bsmWS.Range("A" & bsmWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    a = onlyDigits(bsmWS.Range("A" & i).Value)
    If InStr(a, "T") Then
    ' do something?
    Else
        destlastrow = tabWS.Range("B" & tabWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 2 To destlastrow
            b = onlyDigits(tabWS.Range("B" & j).Value)
            iComp = StrComp(a, b, vbBinaryCompare)
            Select Case iComp
            Case 0
                With tabWS
                    erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                    .Range(.Cells(j, 3), .Cells(j, 4)).Copy .Range(.Cells(erow, 8), .Cells(erow, 9))
                End With     'tabWS
            End Select
        Next j
    End If

Next i
End Sub
```

In your original code, sometimes you correctly gave the sheets for the range, but other times not (you should use `Sheets("whatever").Rows.Count` too). This will hopefully tighten it up and work for you.

Comment: ya code is clear thanks, how to paste "tabWs" in incremented couloumns and take that value into concatenate to "Bsm_Stm_io" in B3 row for only ID "10000"