# WorksheetFunction.value() missing in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

In a spreadsheet formula, `=VALUE("$100")` will evaluate to the numeric value of 100.  I then tried to access this function in VBA via WorksheetFunction object, however it is missing.

In VBA I tried the conversion function `Val("$100")`, however that returns 0.  So how can I accomplish this via VBA?

Comment: `In a spreadsheet formula, =VALUE("$100") will evaluate to the numeric value of 100`  - Are you sure about this ? It didn't evaluate to 100 in my excel. http://imgur.com/a/cEb2k

Comment: @newguy mine doesn't either but interestingly, it's perfectly happy to evaluate "£100" and "€100" to 100

Comment: @danl are you passing a literal string to that function or you are referencing to a cell that is currency formatted. Because if it's a string it wouldn't work. It will work with cell referencing which has the value but it's just formatted.

Comment: @newguy both - I have two cells that are literally typed in as =Value("£100") and =Value("€100"), and two cells that are =Value(B2) for example, where B2 = '£100 or '€100 . Both worked fine, and both methods throw an error when using $ instead of £ or €

Comment: @newguy besides, why would you use Value on a cell that was just formatted as opposed to a string - you're just getting the same value as what's in the cell, which seems a bit of a waste of time (unless you had a mix of values/strings in the column and were trying to get them all the same)

Comment: @danl Yes you are right passing "€100" to Value works but not "$100" don't know why.

Comment: @Allen:Whether `=VALUE("$100")` works or not depends on the locale and Excel's language version. The [Type Conversion Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278896.aspx) are working the same way. So maybe `CDbl("$100")` will work for your Excel in VBA.

Comment: I'm using Excel2013, and positive about =VALUE("$100") equaling 100.

Comment: @newguy - I'm cleaning up data exported from some other app, so not under my control.  Axel - Yes, CDbl() does work in VBA, however it doesn't make sense why VALUE would be missing from the WorksheetFunction object.

Comment: @Allen `It doesn't make sense why VALUE would be missing from the WorksheetFunction object` maybe because you can access value using `Range("A1").Value`

Comment: @newguy - Range("A1").Value will still return the full string, not the numerical value.  So it seems that Axel's recommendation of Cdbl() is the best way to go.

Comment: @Allen : "it doesn't make sense why VALUE would be missing from the WorksheetFunction object". Yes, it doesn't make sense, but I did find that at least the omission is documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/list-of-worksheet-functions-available-to-visual-basic

Answer (score 0):

Val() only really works if the string is all numbers I'm afraid - currency signs cause it a problem.

If you're always going to have the same currency sign in the string, it might be worth using something like

```
StringName = replace(StringName, "$", "")
```

to take out the $ by replacing it with "" - otherwise if your strings aren't always going to be this predictable the below question might help:

[How to find numbers from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239328/how-to-find-numbers-from-a-string)

Comment: *Val() only really works if the string is all numbers I'm afraid* - `? Val("42 Not true")`.

Answer (score 0):

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.numbervalue

example of using above, which will return a value of -1234.56:

```
MsgBox WorksheetFunction.NumberValue("-$1,234.56", ".", ",")
```

Note that if the result is non-numeric, it throws an error. For example (swapping the comma grouping and decimal character params which is invalid in this case):

```
MsgBox WorksheetFunction.NumberValue("-$1,234.56", ".", ",")
```

[image: error detail]

I don't understand why the above link doesn't have any version info. It is currently dated 2019‎-‎05‎-‎23 - no idea if that's because it is new or if it was recently updated.

Comment: WorksheetFunction.NumberValue is only available for Excel 365 or v2019 and above.