# Impossible to convert text in numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to copy/paste many data from pdf to excel. Unfortunately, the format is always in text and I can't convert it despite my formula.

Here is the example :

[image]

Do you have an idea to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try putting a double unary between the = and the rest of the formula.

Comment: Sometimes doing *1 as the final step works as well...

Comment: I tried like this : =--(SUBSTITUE(SUBSTITUE(C2;CAR(160);"");" €";"")) but it doesnt work. I've also tried the CNUM and end the formula with *1

Comment: Just in case you could use an UDF, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/7239408/9199828. It will extract all numbers. Your quantities have 2 decimals. Both will be extracted as integers, so after extracting all numbers, divide by 100 to get the decimal part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to consider space after first two digit `16 000,00 €`. So, substitute space as well. Comma and semicolon depends on region.

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),"€","")," ","")
```

## Edit:

If space is not regular space `in case of Char(160)` then use.

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),"€",""),CHAR(160),"")
```

[image]

Comment: The op's sample seemed to be using a non-breaking space (CHAR(160)) and not a normal space (CHAR(32) or `" "`). The comma seems to be a non-EN-US decimal point.

Comment: Then have to use `Char(160)` instead of regular space like `=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),"€",""),CHAR(160),"")`