# Excel formula, add leading 0 after the dash (-) but before the numbers

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have data that looks like: D-8, FE-09, I-18, P-1 in a range.

I would want all the numbers from 1 to 9 to have a 0 before them. The previous sequence would then be

D-08, FE-09, I-18, P-01

Is there any way to do this with formulas or as a last resort with a macro? I can do this with formulas but it's long since I'm doing it step by step; separating the letters from the numbers in 2 columns, adding the leading 0, putting them back together.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239328/how-to-find-numbers-from-a-string) shows how to find numbers in a string, so it could be adapted to then add `-0` before the number it has found

Comment: You don't need VBA. This is fairly simple. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>"),"-","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*2+1&"]")&"-"&TEXT(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>"),"-","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*2+2&"]"),"00"))
```

[image]

---

Per your comments, having only one value in a per cell:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1))&TEXT(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,2),"00")
```

[image]

Comment: This works, can we simplify it? There is only one set of letter/number per cell. So D-8 is in one cell, FE-09 in another one, etc. They're all on different rows in one column.

Comment: @Jade see edit.  And next time try to be more clear that the values are all in separate cells.

Comment: @Scott do you know of a good reference for XPath as used by FilterXML?

Comment: @chrisneilsen This is what I look at: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/ but it is not always the clearest and as such I have some trial and error on the first pass.

Comment: @Scott thx, I'm still learning XPath. Given the quality of your answers I'm sure that will be a great start.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you. What if some of the values are as such: LF-34C, I don't want the C at the end to be cleared off?

Comment: @Jade That is a new question as that was not in the specs for this question.